# Scene graph child node registration & copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, scenegraph

I have a scene graph, all nodes deriving from a base class `AbstractNode`. `AbstractNode` has a `registerChild` member function:

```
registerChild<T>(string name, shared_ptr<AbstractNode> * childMember)
```

used for registering the children in a standard way (so that they can be listed and modified in the base class interface). It basically adds the name/child_pointer pair to a hash.

So for instance the class material will be declared like that (shortened):

```
class Material : public AbstractNode
{
public:
    Material() { registerChild(&color); } 

private:
    std_shared<Color> color;
}
```

Color being another subclass of AbstractNode.

Now I would like to implement a copy constructor for AbstractNode. It must copy the list of registered children, and update the child member pointers. I would like to avoid reimplementing the copy constructor in all base classes. Is this possible?

I have thought of working on pointer offsets, between `this` and the child pointers. But are these guaranteed to be constant between two instances? It seems like a big hack to me... (And I'm even sure that this is not guaranteed when subclassing)

Thanks,

Etienne

Comment: What on earth is `AbstractNode * shared_ptr<childMember>` supposed to mean?

Comment: Nothing. That's fixed...

Comment: I have a workaround : moving all "registerChild" calls from the derived class constructor to a "registerAll" virtual function. Then this one is called at the first call to a children access function. Not perfect, but working. Any idea on updating the pointer table upon copying, without asking to the derived class author to write more code, would be appreciated!

Comment: Whats the purpose of `shared_ptr<AbstractNode> * childMember`? A pointer to a `std::shared_ptr`????!

Comment: Yes, or if you want to put it simply, a double pointer AbstractNode**, but shared at one stage. Pointers to pointers are commonly used for modifying the object pointed to. You've never used a double pointer????! You've never used shared pointers to avoid memory leaks and dangling pointers????!